# How can I get the author and title by knowing the ISBN using Google Book API?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-books, isbn

[isbntools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbntools/3.3.8) provides several useful methods and functions to validate, clean, transform, hyphenate and get metadata for ISBN strings.

`isbntools` documentation show how to get meta-data using Google Books:

```
$ isbn_meta ISBN goob
```

But that is an example of a command from the bash shell. How can I get the author and title by knowing the ISBN using Google Book API but calling a method from inside python code and not from the bash shell?

Comment: It's great that you self-answered your own question, and the answer is of good quality, but you need to make sure that the question can still be answerable by _other people_. Your post has been closed as "too broad" because there are just too many methods to solve the problem, and you have not shown us any of your attempts.

Comment: That's up to you, I can't / won't give you that advice. I suggest you at least improve your post with as much detail and examples as you can so that it can be re-opened (if nothing else than for good practice).

Comment: solving your answer within 14 mins of posting it is very fast, it is hard when people downvote without giving a reason though

Comment: @Mousey The question was not solved immediately if you check the  answer before the many edits you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some [point](https://github.com/xlcnd/isbntools/issues/88), plugins for metadata and more stuff were moved into `isbnlib`. So now you can get metadata from ISBN like this:

```
import isbnlib

isbn = '9788177581805'

book = isbnlib.meta(isbn)

title = book['Title']
authors = book['Authors]
```

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbnlib/3.6.1) is the documentation for `isbnlib` which contains all the common functions that you may want to use.

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to find clearly in `isbntool` documentation how exactly to use the API to take the meta using Google Books API (the documentation had some shell commands though). I had to look in the source code and this is the working answer:

```
import sys
from isbntools.app import *

isbn = "1883319420"

meta_dict = meta(isbn, service='goob')


print meta_dict['Authors']
print meta_dict['Title']
```

Console output:

```
takeisbn.py[stdout]:    
[u'Mark B. Woodhouse']
takeisbn.py[stdout]:    
Paradigm Wars
```

To make the above code more usefull: if you want to use other online service replace `goob` with `[wcat|goob|openl|isbndb|merge]`

`wcat` uses worldcat.org (no key is needed), `goob` uses the Google Books service (no key is needed), `isbndb` uses the isbndb.com service (an api key is needed), `openl` uses the OpenLibrary.org api (no key is needed), `merge` uses a merged record of `wcat` and `goob` records (no key is needed) and is the default option

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron Ok, thanks, I added the python2.7 label

Comment: @jlansey I run on my computer there were changes  in the isbntools code I edited the answer and now works
Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @TheGr8Adakron can you please check if it works now, I modified the code in the answer